# IVP with modulus

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the following IVP $$y'=2|y| \ \ , \ \ y(0)=1$$

If $y\leq0$ then $y(x)=e^{-2x}$ and if $y\geq0$ then $y(x)=e^{2x}$ . But $y(x)=e^{2|x|}$ is not a plausible solution since it is monotonically decreasing in $(-\infty,0)$ , whereas $y'=2|y|\geq0$ implies $y(x)$ is monotonically increasing everywhere .

What is possibly going wrong here ? Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Notice that $e^{-2x}$ is not non-positive.

Comment: OK , does this imply the IVP has no non-trivial solutions for $x<0$ ?

Comment: Maybe I make an answer on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $y(x)=0$ is a solution of the ODE. As the right side is Lipschitz, no other solution can cross the $x$-axis, the sign of the whole solution is determined by the initial value.

Thus $y(x)=Ce^{2x}$ for $y(0)=C>0$ and $y(x)=Ce^{-2x}$ for $y(0)=C<0$. In both cases the formula is valid over all $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: So we'll have the unique solution $y(x)=\begin{cases}e^{2x} \ \text{if} \  x\geq0 \\ 0 \ \ \ \ \text{if} \ x<0\end{cases}$ . But I'm afraid the solution isn't continuous .

Comment: No, I said the formula is valid for all of $\Bbb R$, there is no discontinuity in value or derivative.

Comment: Then it makes no difference between $y'=2|y|$ and $y'=2y$ at all subject to $y(0)=1>0$ , if it were $y(0)=-1<0$ , then the IVP would be equivalent to $y'=-2y$ . Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct interpretation.